# Checkbox value match, but now show checked in checkbox

Tags: php, if-statement, checkbox

Is there something wrong with my code :

```
if($q_ccd_chk == 'on')
{
    if($q_front == 1)
    {
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="front" value="1" checked/> Front';
    }
    if($q_back == 1)
    {
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="back" value="1" checked/> Back';
    }
    if($q_fb == 1)
    {
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="fb" value="1" checked/> FB';
    }
}
else
{
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="front" value="1"/> Front';
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="back" value="1"/> Back';
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="fb" value="1"/> FB';
}
```

If value checkbox front and back value match, it will show checkbox with checked. But if the 3 of checkbox value match, its not show checked for all checkbox.

Comment: I don't understand your question dude :)

Comment: what's exactly your question?

Comment: checkbox checked based on database, $q_front, $q_back, $q_fb. Example if $q_front == 1, then the checkbox will checked and for $q_back and $q_fb. But now if the 3 of checkbox value is matched, the checkbox is not set checked in each checkbox.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little further.. i didn't got that.

Comment: Did you see my answer at all ?

Answer (score 0):

You only check if `$q_ccd_chk` is on. And if it is not you show all the unchecked values. You should check them ALL before you can do this. If `$q_ccd_chk` is on but the other 3 are not. It shows no checkboxes at all...

Answer (score 0):

What do you get with :

```
$checkedfront = "";
$checkedback  = ""; 
$checkedfb    = ""; 

if($q_ccd_chk == 'on')
{
    if($q_front == 1) { $checkedfront = " checked";}
    if($q_back  == 1) { $checkedback  = " checked";}
    if($q_fb    == 1) { $checkedfb    = " checked";}
}

    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"front\" value=\"1\"".$checkedfront." /> Front\n";
    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"back\" value=\"1\"".$checkedback." /> Back\n";
    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"fb\" value=\"1\"".$checkedfb." /> FB\n";
```